# MFCopy source code

Tags: media, foundation

Does anybody know where the source code of MFCopy and other MSDN Media Foundation blog tools could be found? What might be the reason for removing the source code from MSDN in first place anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found on MFNode website: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mfnode/

Answer (score 1):

try WindowsSDK7-Samples by link on GitHub - [WindowsSDK7-Samples](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples)

Comment: Try on GitHub. It looks like that Microsoft has decided move more code on that repo.

Comment: Tried on GitHub too. Couldn't find it. Thanks anyway.